# "I wonder how do you feel" vs "I wonder how you feel"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I am going to prepare a letter. A piece of that letter is as follows:

"I wonder how you feel about those musics. After all, those are musics from a completely different culture that of your country culture."

I wonder if I should use "how do you feel" instead of "how you feel" in the above context. I found examples of both in the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as johann_ka explained, "music" is an uncountable noun. This means that if you are referring to "music" in plural, you still call it "music" instead of "musics" (and you would say "that music," not "those music"). Also, in your second sentence, you said "[that is music] from a completely different culture that of your country culture." This sentence doesn't grammatically fit together; I suggest saying something like "that is music from a completely different culture than that of your country's culture," because the word "than" compares the "different culture" and "your country's culture" (and the 's after country shows possession).

The sentence "How do you feel about this music?" is a question. You only use the word "do" like that in a question.

The sentence "I wonder how you feel about this music" is not question; it is as statement. You are not asking how the person feels about the music, you are simply saying that you wonder how they feel. Since it is not a question, you don't use the word "do."

Also, I don't know the purpose of your letter, but **if** you are trying to get a response from the person you are addressing the letter to, I would suggest using the question version "How do you feel about this music?" If this doesn't apply to your letter just ignore my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

**1)**
**I wonder how you feel about this music.**
In this sentence 'how' is not a question word (interrogative pronoun) therefore you would NOT use 'do' in this question.

**How do you feel about this music?**
Here the 'I wonder' has been dropped and 'how' is now used as an (interrogative pronoun, although people still say it is an adverb) thus you should use 'do' in your question.

**2)**
Also, 'music' is an uncountable noun, so it must be 'this music', even when it is several/different pieces of music.

Comment: I need some simple examples in plain English to understand the answer. It is a shame that I can't understand your answer.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and look this up in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. It has many examples. No need to copy them in here.

Comment: Thank you. but would you please give me the title that I should search in that dictionary?

Comment: Simply look up the word 'how'.

Comment: I had plenty of works. After I did  that, I searched the word "how" in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. I could not find my answer. I need someone to answer my question in a very easy to understand way and with simple and plain examples.

Comment: @ARAM - you must look up the following:  1) forming sentences with "how" in simple present (2) building questions with "how" in simple present